# Slim in PHP problems with redirecting to signup page

Tags: html, anchor

So by sending `localhost/path/home` will take me to the homepage, login and signup is included, so when I click either login or signup will sent out `localhost/path/login` or signup that will take me to login or signup page.

Here is the problem:
In `login.html` I have html tag should forward to the signup page.

```
<p>Don't have an account yet? <a href="/signup">SignUp here</a>.</p>
```

However what happen is that `localhost/signup` is sent out, when I try to change it to:

```
<p>Don't have an account yet? <a href="path/signup">SignUp here</a>.</p>
```

It actually sends out `localhost/path/path/signup`, anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: /path/signup maybe work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you shouldn't have the first /slash/ there... If they are on localhost/path/login, the link should just be href="signup" so that it goes to localhost/path/signup... On a website, if you were on website.com/path/login, you would click "href="signup" and be taken to website.com/path/signup

```
<p>Don't have an account yet? <a href="signup">SignUp here</a>.</p>
```

localhost/path/ is the current directory of the file being accessed and is the same as website.com/path/ . So, knowing this - you do not need to include /path in your URLs, because the page being displayed is already in /path/ folder, so your links can be directly relative to other files inside the same /path/

If you're on localhost/path/file.html for example, you can access any file also in /path/ by just calling the file name (with extension if required) - no need for full path. If you wanted to do a link to a file in another folder (such as localhost/path2/file2.html) you could link to it from path/file.html like this:

```
<a href="../path2/file2.html">File 2</a>
```

I hope this helps you understand relative file includes, links, images, etc - The logic is very similar for all of those :)

Comment: This answer is great for explaining _but_, unless the login system is specific to `/path/`, an absolute URL should be favoured because it's either in a templating system or going to be copied and pasted all over the place.

Comment: He already told us that it's a link that goes from path/signup page (that user is actually ON - not included elsewhere), so the relative links like this work for his use case. But yes, I personally prefer to run everything off of root/index.php and use ?gets or AJAX to load in views. So I get in the habit of $_SERVER[] vars basically, and that works well for this type of thing. But for this OP, it does seem that this link is specifically for the signup page (site.com/path/signup) and not being used in a footer for example.

Comment: In this particular instance that's where it is, so there's little harm. But then that link might well get copied and tweaked, since that's a known location of a working link. Then the link stops working... But with knowledge of how it works, I suppose it shouldn't be too hard to debug...

Answer (score -1):

You changed it from a domain-relative link to a directory-relative link. Change it to:

```
<p>Don't have an account yet? <a href="/path/signup">SignUp here</a>.</p>
```

to fix the problem.

Comment: just figure it out if I change it to:

                      <a href="signup">Signup here</a>.</p>

it also work, which is better?

Comment: Yes, ZQ - just href="signup". My answer  that I just posted has this solution, as well as some info about relative URLs & paths.